# How can I Loop through a Range using Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to use a Case through a Range to prompt a message box. I was advised to use a For Loop to go through a range of more than one.

Now whenever I do that it provides a "Compile Error:  Next without For"

I know every for statement needs a next which I've tried to include, but each time I do I get extra errors.

How can I resolve this?

```
Dim myRange As Range

For Each myRange In Range("I6,I1000")

Select Case myRange.Value
    Case "7 - engaged"
    VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank", 1, "Status Change"


Next myRange

End Select
```

I am writing this so any time a cell is changed to '7 - Engaged' the message ox is fired (which will fire another macro later).

Comment: just to point out that `Range("I6,I1000")` references two cells ("I6" and "I1000"), while `Range("I6:I1000")` would reference cells from "I6" through "I1000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an ordering issue.You need to close the `Select Case` before the `Next`

```
Dim myRange As Range

For Each myRange In Activesheet.Range("I6:I1000") '<== better to use actual sheet name in reference

    Select Case myRange.Value
        Case "7 - engaged"
        VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Client status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank", 1, "Status Change"

    End Select
Next myRange
```

Your description implies you probably want to look at a [worksheet change event](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel). See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). Note this is not for cells that change by calculation.

Comment: Thank you!

I have made that adjustment, but now it is only firing the message box if the case occurs in I6, not in any others of the range,

I am not sure if that is a Case issue or something else?

Comment: For Each myRange In Activesheet.Range("I6:I1000")